# Unreachable following new install 20.04 LTS (in vmware7)

Tags: networking, server

New install from ISO 20.04 LTS server

Host is not reachable, and VM client can't even ping the gateway. Since I only have vmware console, I can only show clips: What did I mess up?

The netplan file:

[image: netplan file]

The route:

[image: route]

The IP info:

[image: IP info]

Comment: Usually the guest OS in VM automatically connect to the internet, if the host OS is connected. Was it not your case? Did you edit any system config files?

Comment: It's plain vanilla as installed - untouched

Comment: What error message do you get, when you try to ping the gateway: Timeout, network unreachable, no route to host? And the usual question: Did you try to turn it off and on again?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies.

When building the VM, there was a single VLAN available to select. So I built the VM using that.

It turns out there was a 'super-secret' VLAN that I wasn't able to see or select.

Once the vmware team parked my NIC on the correct VLAN, I was fixed.

Comment: Have you tried virtualbox? From my experience, networking works out of the box there.